# How to make css active only in one table? (duplicate table class)

Tags: html, css

I have 2 tables with same class elements like:

```css
/* and css to make number increases in Numbers List col */

.myTbl tbody {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

.myTbl tbody tr {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

.myTbl tbody tr td:nth-child(1)::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
  min-width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
 <div class="tableRow">
<table class="myTbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Numbers List</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </div>

  <div class="tableRow">
  <table class="myTbl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>C</th>
          <td>D</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </div>
```

I want the css only active in specific table like table 1 , but I'm having duplicate classes. How to do it?

And I cant affect the html table like change class or add id,... cause It's exported from other, only js or jquery to do it.

I tried adding ::nth-child(1) not working, is there a way same like eq() in js?

Comment: Did you try `:nth-of-type(1)`?

Comment: which table do you want to target and are your tables siblings (ie do they have the same parent container)

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina I tried that and `:first` but not work.

Comment: @pete I want to add to table 1 or whichever specific table, since they're have same class.

Comment: if they  are in the same container, you can use the [general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) or [adjacent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) sibling combinator - if it's the first table, style it and then remove the styles from the second table; if it's the second table, then just style it.  I'm guessing nth-child doesn't work because they're not the only elements in your container but as you haven't created a [mcve] it's hard to tell

Comment: I figured out how it doesn't work cause I have `div class` in each table, here the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/7bfLm2hz/). Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

`:first-child` or `nth-child(1)` are actually work, you need to select from the parent

```css
body .myTbl:first-child tbody {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<table class="myTbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Numbers List</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <table class="myTbl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: _":first-child or nth-child(1) are actually work"_ - only if the first table actually is the first child of the parent, which we currently don't know.

Comment: you're right, but I assume the structure is exactly what he wrote

Comment: I figured out how it doesn't work cause I have `div class` in each table, here the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/7bfLm2hz/). Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

First, you had unclosed tags.
Second, Using pseudo selectors is the key. But there is a [difference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-first-child-and-first-of-type-selector-in-css/#:%7E:text=The%20%3Afirst%2Dchild%3A%20The,every%20element%20of%20it%27s%20parent.) between `:first-child` & `:first-of-type`.

```css
/* and css to make number increases in Numbers List col */

.myTbl tbody {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

.myTbl tbody tr {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

/* OR :first-child */
.myTbl:first-of-type tbody tr:first-of-type td::before {
  content: '•';
  min-width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Numbers List</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="myTbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I figured out how it doesn't work cause I have `div class` in each table, here the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/7bfLm2hz/). Any solutions?